# How to prevent HTTP Host Header Injection in the Apache module (Apache 2.4.55) if IP address and port number are static

Tags: apache, http

How to prevent HTTP Host Header Injection in the Apache module (Apache 2.4.55) if IP address and port number are not static

pervent redirect to one ip to other ip if ip change by using intercept tool like burp or other intercept tool